# Using a different UIViewcontroller to control UISearchDisplayController 

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a tableview with nsfetchedresultscontroller.  I would like to setup search with uisearchdisplaycontroller. I would like to separate the search results into a different viewcontroller file.  I am able to do that but if i set the `contentestcontroller` to another controller other then `self` then the delegate methods work but the tableview doesn't show. I was able to get this setup working by setting uisearchbar delegate to self and pass the serchtext to the other tableview controller but i would like to have it all working in the search tableview controller.

Do i need to make some connections or in general this would not be a good idea?

Here is some code

This is in viewdidload for the maincontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.peopleListSearch = [[PeopleListSearchViewController alloc] init];

    self.peopleSearchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.debug = NO;
    self.isSearching = NO;
    self.peopleSearchBar.delegate = self.peopleListSearch;
    self.searchBarController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.peopleSearchBar contentsController:self.peopleListSearch];
    self.searchBarController.searchResultsDelegate = self.peopleListSearch;
    self.searchBarController.searchResultsDataSource = self.peopleListSearch;
</code>
```

This is the main tableview controller which works.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    self.peopleListSearch.searchTerm = searchBar.text;
    [self.peopleListSearch performSearch];
    [self.searchBarController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Is there method that is called to show the tableview of the uisearchdisplay controller.

Thanks in advance!